# Making plans for the villain's arrival in a thousand years

Tags: magic

How might a high-fantasy medieval style civilization go about preparing itself for a Big Bad that they know will arrive in 1000 years? There isn't much technology at first but it and magic advances at least a little during the intervening years. It is a small kingdom initially but builds up strong infrastructure and trade relations by the time the big bad arrives.

The big bad was banished but she has no clear weaknesses except for the magic they used to banish it. The banishment was unpredictable magic and requires carefully arranged events to get right. They might not be able to pull it off again. (It was a long term and convoluted ritual, basically.)

On top of sheer power, the big bad employs a purified elemental magic—rather than the chaotic mix that most gather from the environment—which grants her unique finesse and capabilities. E.g. Normal magic users can—with effort—make a wall permeable to passage, like it's a wall of honey. She, however, can make *herself* intangible and pass through whatever she likes.

It's like the difference between heating water to 90° and dropping a fireball on it. They both get the job done but one's messier and and may have nasty side-effects. The big bad's magic is potentially reproducible via refinement of normal magic, however.

Note that "preparing for the big bad" can mean either vanquishing it or simply learning to live under her rule. Actual success need not be probable, just realistic. I'm looking for how a civilization might alter its world when driven towards a specific goal.

Comment: My running idea is that she enacts intense scientific programs. Schooling the best and brightest in an Ender's Game type fashion, perhaps, but focused on researching offensive or defensive magic/technology.
Another idea is that she enacts an "age of exploration" type deal to find kingdoms or artifacts that are powerful enough to defeat the evil.

Comment: Is there any reason why she cannot use the same method again to reseal the evil away for another thousand years?  Also what is it sealed in?  If it is sealed in a portable artifact then there are more options then if it is sealed to a specific location on the planet.

Comment: I'm tempted to say this isn't about world building. This is idea generation for what your characters could or should do. This is story-driven, not worldbuilding. Or am I looking at that wrong? (VTC)

Comment: That does sound like a fair point, @Fayth85. I did post this question cause it presented a hurdle regarding some plotting. But I don't expect this to change the direction of the plot that much. And aren't the setting and story often made for one another?

Comment: @Silhalnor Yes. But this isn't 'character building SE'. It's worldbuilding. As such, all questions are meant to be geared towards the building of the world itself. The politics, the royalty system, the schooling, the weapons, the magic system, the beings to be found. Not "I don't know what to do with my character, or my plot. Idea generation time!" Otherwise this might become a 'write by popular vote' site, not a site geared towards helping to sharpen the world around the characters and plot. You see what I mean?

Comment: @Fayth85 Hmm... Okay, I think I understand. I think this is more about world building, though. One reason is that the "hero" as I called her isn't actually a main character. She may well never actually show up. This is all _backstory_ to help me understand the world the main cast actually live in. The personality of this historic hero doesn't even need to be clearly defined beyond "cares for the people." But she happens to be in a position of power that will shape the land and some generation of ideas will move me from "stupid ideas" to "things someone might actually do."

Comment: We need more details about the Big Bad: powers, immunities, etc.

Comment: @Silhalnor I see what you mean... but that's still a character. If you were to change that to 'organization', then it could be a power within the world which has the power to shift the flow of time, culminating in something. But as is worded. It's just a character, and that character is just a person, with an opinion. (wording is everything)

Comment: Let me give you an example of why the wording matters. With a character (1 person), if I envision this character to be bat shit crazy, I can say they sit on the toilet for a thousand years and ponder the universe. Is it a good plan? No, but it could be in character. And that makes it very opinion based, as opposed to an organization that is putting a thousand years of thought and effort into defeat the lord of toilet dunking.

Comment: @Fayth85 So... if I simply reword this to... what, a long-lived clan within the world that shapes it to this purpose... that would be better? Or that government itself it stable enough for such a thing?
Well... Hehe, this _is_ writing, I suppose. Wording literally _is_ everything! Not sure what alternative would be realistic, though?

Comment: It's actually not very hard to make preparations for 1000 years and fail.  Most long preparations fail.

Comment: Consider the variety of answers we can see in prior art.  The Iron Fist has the sages of K'un-Lun who decided to squirrel themselves away to protect against the Big Bad.  Then there's Stick, who lead The Chaste, taking a direct combat role against the Big Bad.  Then there's Hari Seldon, from the Foundation series, who decided to create an entire branch of science/mathematics in order to stymie the Big Bad over the course of thousands of years.  Quite the diverse set of options!

Comment: I don't know what would actually be useful here, @Tenryu. The big bad possesses illusion and _significant_ combative powers. Like, conjuring blasts of pure energy if she so desires. Or vanishing from sight in an instant. Or teleportation via "regular" magic. But most pertinently, she will be altering the people's way of life by way of blotting out the sun. It probably _is_ worth noting that she won't directly kill unless provoked, however. Kind of a force of nature in that regard. Like if aliens stopped by to harvest all our hydrogen.

Comment: @Silhalnor Probably the three most important bits for this are to: 1. Characterise the scope of the problem (an evil wizard with illusion powers and teleportation is attacking in 1000 years), 2. Set the parameters of the problem (eg. All the resources of a small medieval kingdom to allocate as you see fit against the wizard) and 3. State the problem (What preparations can be made against the wizard's return?). If magic is significantly involved, I'd also recommend being very careful to state what it can do - and, more importantly, that it can't do anything more.

Comment: @Silhalnor How about. "What can a long-lived organization do to stop this big bad with [state skills] in a thousand years?" You can add and subtract as needed, but it still feels very story based. How about "What can the government do to prevent this big bad from coming to power?" But, still quite story based when worded that way. Ooh! I know. Go to the chat here on WBSE, and just ask in there. "Hey, I'm hitting my head against this problem. How can I word this? Or how can I solve it directly?" We love these kinds of discussions here, just in chat, and not in questions on the site.

Comment: @Fayth85 There's a chatroom? I'm busy with other things at the moment but I'll see about coming back to this when I have the chance. Thank you for the suggestions, though!

Comment: @Silhalnor https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

What your population needs here is to be vaccinated from the Big Bad.

Vaccines today are essentially cut down versions of the disease one wishes protection from; the idea is that the pathogens encourage the creation of antibodies in the blooodstream, but not introduce the worst of the symptoms of the disease itself. (This is a simplification but functionally accurate.)

So; your immortal needs to become the Little Bad. Attack the nation in a controlled manner that forces them to become more adept at magic, war, science, etc. in order to thwart the attacks. These have to be real, life-threatening scenarios that the population can't defeat with their current skills and thinking. Force them to grow. Force them to become more competent in the areas they'll need in the future to combat the Big Bad.

Sure; the population will come to fear and hate the Hero. They'll see her as a threat to their lives, one they are forced to constantly thwart, especially after a couple of centuries when the memory of the Big Bad has faded. Your hero is forced to live the life of a pariah for a time too. One can only hope that after the Big Bad is finally defeated, the population come to learn the hero's intent and she can be somewhat forgiven.

The point here is one of priority; people living in a peaceful environment are not going to prioritise preparations for an event in the distant future, no matter how much you may want them to. Also, you can't just take a peaceful nation with no other natural threats and raise a standing army from among them. If you want proof of that, look at the idealised view of WW1 that prevailed among soldiers of both sides before they actually saw action. Very few of them were ready for the reality of war and the technology that was brought to bear was refined *during* that war, not *before* it started.

So, in short, to get your population ready to fight a large threat, you first have to make them adept (through actual practice) at fighting smaller ones.

Comment: I find this idea hilarious and very intriguing. I don't know if I can use it in my story but you make very important points regardless. Maybe if she does so in an undercover fashion but her fire magic has a definite signature... then again, it could be mistaken for dragons. Hmm! I will definitely consider the forced militarization angle regardless.

Comment: If you look at how many disciplines are maintained, this is exactly the approach that is taken.  The Drill Sergent becomes your Little Bad, with the end goal of preparing you for the Big Bad, whatever that might be.

Comment: I just might take this idea. It's a great one.

Answer (score 2):

Organise an order of guardians who are carefully selected for their unique abilities and strength. Their ultimate goal is to confront the big bad, but in the meantime they are guardians of society who are sent out to hone their skills and establish a heroic tradition against all the various little bad guys running around out there. They become an order that passes on it's traditions and knowledge to succeeding generations of guardians perfecting their tactics and knowledge towards to goal of being able to confront the long prophesied return of the big-bad. Maybe society forgets about the big bad and begins to claim he's just a metaphoric legend and never actually literally existed. They view the order of guardians as archaic, backwards, and somewhat odd, but they have a real track record of dealing with other hazards so they are still looked up to. But the guardians never forgot their purpose, and as the time draws nigh for the big bad's rebirth they put everything they have learned and all the power and wealth they have accumulated over a thousand years to the task of preparing. They establish secret groups of lesser believers who didn't make the cut for full guardian status but are still useful lead by one or two full members. They establish these resistance cells anywhere they can so that when the big bad awakens they will be spread out and ready to wage a protracted campaign of resistance against the dark lord of evilness.

That way your order of heroes doesn't get outright obliterated as soon as big-nasty awakens, and are able to slowly and carefully engage him on their own terms until the opportune moment arises to attack him in full force. They are basically spending a thousand years planning every opportunity to get in lord badness's way with minimal risk to themselves until the moment to defeat or banish him arises.

Answer (score 0):

A thousand years is a really long time. Society back then wouldn't even be remotely like society 1000 years later.

If you look at humanity for the last 1000 years, we have come from virtually the tail end of the Iron Age through the Industrialization, Nuclear Age and into the Information Age.

Your Big Bad would really have to be something awesome and extremely adaptable to be able to cope with 1000 years of change especially with an immortal ruler who knows what will happen and has been preparing.

Personally I think your Big Bad needs to be locked out, not locked up. This would mean your Big Bad would also have 1000 years to prepare and would come in with new tricks and strategies and would be even stronger than before.

Comment: I think I can make that happen. But I could also say that magic / magitech is insanely complicated and development is therefore slow. More like protein folding than mechanical engineering. "Locking out" would fit in well with my story even better.